# Tag cleanup for [activation] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

There is an [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) tag, that has no description associated and is mostly used for questions concerning [windows-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-activation) (which exist as tag and has an appropriate description). I saw one question though, that used it in the context of activating an hyperlink in a website. If a more general tag than [windows-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-activation) is needed, it should be named [software-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-activation), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that questions tagged [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) should be retagged appropriately as it is ambiguous and redundant. Questions about activating software other than Windows should get their own tag as you've suggested.

Most of the questions under [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) are about Windows activation, so we should look at all of the questions under this tag and retag the questions about activating other software to [software-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-activation). Afterwards, the tag [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) can be merged into [windows-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-activation). As part of this process, the tag wiki excerpt for [windows-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-activation) can be edited to direct users to tag other software activation questions [software-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-activation), so that confusion can be avoided.

The hyperlink activation question has nothing to do with any of this, so I've removed the [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) tag from the question.

---

### Update

All of the non-Windows activation questions under [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) have been retagged accordingly, and I've proposed a tag wiki for [software-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-activation). [activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/activation) can now be merged into [windows-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-activation).

Comment: "activation can now be merged into windows-activation" - Done